# Struct reference by value - can I get members of a struct programmatically

Tags: c++, struct, reference

I have some code (just a sample bit right now):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string(the_value) = "three";
string(a) = "";

struct Speeds
{
    int s1;
    int s2;
    int s_t;
};

int return_values(Speeds byval) {
    std::cout << "speed1:   " << byval.s1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "speed2:  " << byval.s2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "time: " << byval.s_t << "\n";
    return(1);
}

int main() 
{
    Speeds one = { 255, 200, 1000 };
    Speeds two = { 128, 128, 1000 };
    Speeds three = { 0, 255, 1000 };
    a = the_value;
    cout << "Displaying Information," << endl;

    // Here is the issue at hand:

    // this works and compiles:
    return_values(three);

    // this doesn't:
    return_values(a);
}
```

As you can see in the code and comments - one method works, one does not. So the underlying question becomes - if the member id of the struct Speeds is NOT a string:

1) what is it?

2) Can it be referenced through a variable type other than string?

If #2 is no, then how would I accomplish the same thing with another dictionary type object?

I am new to c++ and teaching myself as I go, and I am pretty sure I saw a reference to this (kind of) buried in another question somewhere, but I cannot find it again. This code is a POC essentially as part of a larger project where I need to store a finite number of struct elements, but retrieve them programmatically by value, not directly by "naming" each one in the function call.

(Also, I know I probably don't need to declare "the_value", and then convert it to another variable "a". It was left over from other things I tried, and irrelevant since "string" doesn't work anyway.)

Comment: You're looking for references (and/or pointers)

Comment: I don't completely understand the question and the intention here but the reason your last line doesn't compile is because `return_values( Speeds byval )` expects a parameter of type `Speed` whereas `a` is of type `std::string`.
return_values(three) compiles because three here is not a `std::string` but of type `Speeds` as defined `Speeds three = { 0, 255, 1000 };`
But then again, maybe i didn't understand your question right.

Comment: I updated the wording (before your edit) to hopefully make more sense. The question fundamentally is, is there a way to call the function without stating the explicit id of the member of the struct?

Comment: Are you looking for an associative container, like a `std::map`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'member id'? There's no such thing in C++. Clearly you have something wrong in your understanding of C++, but I really don't know what it is. I think I agree with Miles, you are look for a `std::map` to do what you want.

Comment: john, I did a lot of reading on the std::map construct and for what I am doing it did not seem viable? I found maps with multiple key:value pairs where you have to list the same key multiple times, with different "values" attached to it, and then iterate them to get all the values. In this way, a struct seemed infinitely more elegant .

I know I do not have the names correct in my question, because I do not know c++ well. What I mean by "member ID" is that you assign the "members" of the struct by defining them with the statement: "Speeds one" where "one" is what I have called the member ID.